# Bucket Sort Algorithm Code Issues

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to implement the following in java.

Input: an array of integers

Output: Rearrange the array to have the following:

Suppose the first element in the original array has the value `x`
In the new array, suppose that x is in position I, that is `data[I] = x`. Then, `data[j] <= x` for all `x` and for all `j > I`. This means that all the values to the "left" of `x` are less than or equal to x and all the values to the "right" are larger than `x`.

An example is as follows: Suppose the array has the elements in this initial order: 4,3,9,2,7,6,5. After applying your algorithm, you should get: 3,2,4,5,9,7,6. That is, the leftmost element, 4, is positioned in the resulting array so that all elements less than 4 (2 and 3) are to its left (in no particular order), and all elements larger than 4 are to its right (in no particular order).

There is no space requirement for the algorithm, only that the problem is solved in O(n) time.
I have implemented a bucket sort, but am having some difficulties with the code.

```
public class Problem4 
{
    public static void partition(int[] A)
    {
        int x = A[0];
        int l = A.length;
        int[] bucket = int [];      
        for(int i=0; i<bucket.length; i++){
            bucket[i]=0;
        }
        for (int i=0; i<l; i++){
            bucket[x[i]]++;
        }
        int outPos=0;
        for(int i=0; i<bucket.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<bucket[i]; j++){
                x[outPos++]=i;
            }
        }
     }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] A = {4,3,9,2,7,6,5};

        System.out.println("Before partition:");
        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(A[i] + " ");
        }       
        partition(A);

        System.out.println("After partition:");

        System.out.println("Before partition:");
        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(A[i] + " ");           
        }           
    }
}
```

The lines:

- `int[] bucket = int[]`,
- `bucket[x[i]]++;`, and
- `x[outpost++] = i`;

are causing me troubles. I am getting the error

> The type of expression must be an array type but is resolved to an int.

The problem stems from that first line where I am trying to create a new array called bucket. I would appreciate any suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: Does this even compile? `int[] bucket = int [];  `

Comment: @Kaushal28 Nope!

Comment: lol @JacobG....

Comment: Maybe a small point (given that the code has syntax errors), but I would not choose `partition` as the name for the distribution method in Bucket Sort. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort

Comment: This would make a much better question if you construct a [mcve] and ask a question like "how do I create an array", although answers to questions like those are probably better found in a textbook or tutorial (since you might be missing out on a lot of the surrounding context needed to learn the basics of a language, which will just lead to a whole bunch more questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to resort to a bucket sort. Instead you can simply walk through the array, placing elements that are less than the split value at the front and elements that are greater at the back. We can use two variables, `front` and `back` to keep track of the insert position at the front and back of the array. Starting at position 1 in the array, if the value is less than the split value we place at `front` and increment `front` and the current index. If the value is greater we swap it with the value at `back` and decrement `back`, but we keep the current index.

Here's some code to illustrate:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] A = {4,3,9,2,7,6,5};      
    sort(A);        
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
}

public static void sort(int[] arr)
{
    int split = arr[0];

    int front = 0;
    int back = arr.length-1;
    for(int i=1; front != back; )
    {
        if(arr[i] <= split)
        {
            arr[front] = arr[i];
            front += 1;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            swap(arr, i, back);
            back -= 1;
        }
    }
    arr[front] = split;
}

public static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j)
{
    int t = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = t;
}
```

Output:

```
[3, 2, 4, 7, 6, 5, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you! this is a lot simpler! Am I correct in saying it has a run time of O(n)?

Comment: Yes, you're just iterating over the n elements of the array, assigning or swapping 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you can use is to use the standard partition algorithm of [QuickSort](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/).

I have modified your code and the following code

```
public class Problem4 
{

    /* This function takes last element as pivot,
       places the pivot element at its correct
       position in sorted array, and places all
       smaller (smaller than pivot) to left of
       pivot and all greater elements to right
       of pivot */
    public static int partition(int arr[], int low, int high)
    {
        int pivot = arr[high]; 
        int i = (low-1); // index of smaller element
        for (int j=low; j<high; j++)
        {
            // If current element is smaller than or
            // equal to pivot
            if (arr[j] <= pivot)
            {
                i++;

                // swap arr[i] and arr[j]
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        // swap arr[i+1] and arr[high] (or pivot)
        int temp = arr[i+1];
        arr[i+1] = arr[high];
        arr[high] = temp;

        return i+1;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] A = {4,3,9,2,7,6,5};

        System.out.println("Before partition:");
        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(A[i] + " ");
        }       

        // swap and call the standard partition algo of QuickSort 
        // on last element pivot. swap arr[low] and arr[high]
        int low = 0;
        int high = A.length-1;

        int temp = A[low];
        A[low] = A[high];
        A[high] = temp;

        partition(A, low, high);

        System.out.println("\nAfter partition:");

        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(A[i] + " ");           
        }   
    }
}
```

**Outputs**

```
Before partition:
4 3 9 2 7 6 5 
After partition:
3 2 4 5 7 6 9
```

Hope it helps!